# Toggle angle to move text to original position in fabricjs

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

In `fabricjs`, `onclick` of button I'm setting some angle to flip the text. I want to make it toggle on next click text should come back to original. In below code if part works well how should I toggle it back?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnzhq/3/)

JQuery code:

```
 $('#font_flipx').click(function() {

    if(flipx==0)
    {
        console.log('flipx=0');
    canvas.getActiveObject().set("angle", "180").set('flipX', true);
    flipx=1;
    }
    else
    {

    console.log('flipx=1');
    canvas.getActiveObject().set("angle", "180").set('flipX', true);
    flipx=0;
    }

    canvas.renderAll();


});
```

Comment: @koala_dev setting 0 doesn't works ... text is still shown with mirror image

Comment: what is the expected behavior? do you want to rotate and flipX on first click and return to default on next? like this http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/vnzhq/4/ ?

Comment: @koala_dev u helped me :) ..  as you said changeing angle to 0 this was not working with my log if-else http://jsfiddle.net/vnzhq/5/  code , dont know why ? bt you really give me short and sweet code

Comment: Glad to help. I've posted an answer, please accept it if your issue has been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your flag variable to adjust the angle and flipx parameter, you can shorten your code to:

```
var flipx = false;
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
    flipx = !flipx;
    canvas.getActiveObject().set("angle", flipx ? "180" : "0").set('flipX', flipx);
    canvas.renderAll();
};
```